Why does the consumer stop reading from the topic?
The service suddenly stops reading from part of the queues, usually one or two in a concumer group.
It happens after rebanning of kafka. You can see the logs below.
Until the moment of the problem I see in the output kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group quote-log-service id member , but after it disappears.
If I delete the group consumer and restart the application -- everything starts working again again, again up to a certain point.
MemberID: kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-0f6d99fd-58e5-4e2b-8a9f-3a5438a166f9
Some memberID kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-6fd6d9ae-e843-4d42-9c67-beecd22fa9ae also appears in the logs below, it feels like the app is trying to connect with the new id but kafka won't let it.

[2024-04-26 13:11:19,734] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to
rebalance group quote-log-service in state PreparingRebalance with old
generation 3 (__consumer_offsets-5) (reason: Removing member
kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-0f6d99fd-58e5-4e2b-8a9f-3a5438a166f9
on LeaveGroup; client reason: the consumer is being closed)
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-26 13:11:19,734] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member
MemberMetadata(memberId=kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-0f6d99fd-58e5-4e2b-8a9f-3a5438a166f9,
groupInstanceId=None, clientId=kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in,
clientHost=/172.16.124.236, sessionTimeoutMs=45000,
rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, supportedProtocols=List(range,
cooperative-sticky)) has left group quote-log-service through explicit
LeaveGroup; client reason: the consumer is being closed
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-26 13:11:20,844] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group
quote-log-service generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-5) with 7 members
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-26 13:11:21,328] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment
received from leader
kafka-consumer-quotelog-multi-module-validation-in-3107100c-edda-4f20-90b8-57ad747da8ab
for group quote-log-service for generation 4. The group has 7 members,
0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-26 13:11:23,349] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to
rebalance group quote-log-service in state PreparingRebalance with old
generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-5) (reason: Removing member
kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-6fd6d9ae-e843-4d42-9c67-beecd22fa9ae
on LeaveGroup; client reason: the consumer is being closed)
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2024-04-26 13:11:23,349] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member
MemberMetadata(memberId=kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in-6fd6d9ae-e843-4d42-9c67-beecd22fa9ae,
groupInstanceId=None, clientId=kafka-consumer-quotelog-osago-in,
clientHost=/172.16.124.234, sessionTimeoutMs=45000,
rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, supportedProtocols=List(range,
cooperative-sticky)) has left group quote-log-service through explicit
LeaveGroup; client reason: the consumer is being closed
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

I have no name!@87402d74c30f:/$  kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group quote-log-service

    GROUP             TOPIC                                        PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                              HOST            CLIENT-ID
    quote-log-service quotation-kasko-write-v1                     0          4820            4820            0               kafka-consumer-quotelog-kasko-in-1312108a-5fdf-4ef5-8985-097d8961ae07                    /172.16.124.234 kafka-consumer-quotelog-kasko-in
    quote-log-service quotelog-multi-module-calculation-write-v1   0          17454           17454           0               kafka-consumer-quotelog-multi-module-calculation-in-0d974be7-a6e9-4316-a5f4-ae9b942e2fbb /172.16.124.236 kafka-consumer-quotelog-multi-module-calculation-in
    quote-log-service quotelog-multi-module-validation-in-write-v1 0          2091            2091            0               kafka-consumer-quotelog-multi-module-validation-in-21212baf-ea75-47ab-93c2-daff56bbb566  /172.16.124.234 kafka-consumer-quotelog-multi-module-validation-in
    quote-log-service quotation-osago-write-v1                     0          3900            4156            256             -   

             

